# DataIntegrityViolationException in CrudRepository.exists method

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, unique-constraint

In my service, have handled `DataIntegrityViolationException` when calling `myCrudRepository.saveAndFlush` to handle concurrent persist (insertion) requests. It works and I can catch the exception. After this, I prefer to make sure if the exception is exactly because entity already exists, not due to any other possible unknown issues. So, I call `myCrudRepository.exists(entity.getId())` , but `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown again.
Here is my simple code:

```
private void save(final Employee entity) throws MyAppException {
    try{
        this.myCrudRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
    }catch (org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e){
        // check if the error is really because the entity already exists
        // entity.getId() is already generated before any save. it's like National ID
        boolean exists = this.myCrudRepository.exists(entity.getId()); // DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown here again!
        if (exists)
            throw new MyAppException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "Entity already exists.");
        else
            throw e;
    }
}
```

But if I use `findOne` instead of `exists`, it works fine. It's somehow strange, but of course it has a technical reason that I'm not good enough to make a guess.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are using Transactional method and after the method returns the transaction will auto commit and hibernate will wrap up the exceptions into another one. Actually the exception is occurring when transaction commits and at that time you are out of that method already. To catch the exception from inside the method you can simply use `em.flush()` after `this.myCrudRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually, I think `exists` method is trying to flush unsaved changes before fetching data (to be more accurate and reliable), following the default flush strategy. That's why same exception is thrown again on call of `exists` method. So, `em.clear()` makes more sense here compared to `em.flush()`. But I'm not sure if basically it's a good practice.

Comment: what basically i am seeing here is there is no chance of causing any exception inside your method unless you use `em.flush()`. so, if you use `em.flush()` then `DataIntegrityViolationException` will be thrown since it immediately will try to execute database save operation and only if it finds a duplicate rows

Comment: Yes. exactly. `myCrudRepository.exists` method calls the `flush` method internally (as I saw in Hibernate stack trace), so all you mentioned is happening. It faces an existing record in DB and the `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception is thrown again.